# Number of ways to send http request to remote address and return response in Java+Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, httprequest, httpresponse, remote-server

I have some doubts about possible ways of sending a request to a remote address, and then return that response in Springboot using Java language. So far I tried to do that only using CloseableHttpClient and CloseableHttpResponse, making rest post call to the address, and then return a response (yet I've been so far unable to read the response properly, since method EntityUtils.getString() has been throwing exceptions.. [Extracting JSON from response as ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8,Chunked: true]}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220523/extracting-json-from-response-as-responseentityproxycontent-type-application) )
Does anyone have maybe some other idea how can that be achieved, are there other possible ways how one can send an HTTP request(with headers and body) and read the response, in these technologies?(or at least in some other technologies if it's not possible in these..).
I would greatly appreciate any kind of help or suggestion.

Comment: What you are going to send to ```API``` as ```POST``` request?

Comment: I am trying to send binary file, image or video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there are two common ways to make `API` reqests in `Spring Boot`.

1. **RestTemplate**
2. **WebClient**

Most of people todat use commonly `RestTemplate`. But it is going to be deprecated in coming years. So that I recommend you to use `WebClient`.

Below `WebClient` **POST REQUEST** Example:

```
 @Autowired
 private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;


 Turnover turnover = new Turnover();
                
 Gson resp = webClientBuilder.build()
 .post()
 .uri("url")
 .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
 .body(Mono.just(turnover),Turnover.class)
 .retrieve()
 .bodyToMono(Gson.class).block();
```

`Turnover.java`

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Turnover {

    private String start_date;
    private String end_date;
    private String account;

    public Turnover(){
        setStart_date("01.01.2020");
        setEnd_date("01.06.2020");
        setAccount("20293435454");
    }
}
```

`webClientBuilder Bean`. In my case I had `PROXY`. So that I used proxy url and port.

```
@Bean
    public WebClient.Builder getWebClientBuilder(){

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient ->
                        tcpClient.proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).host("url").port(portnumber)));
        ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
        return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector);
    }
```

`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And don`t forget to create `Bean` of WebClient in your Main java class. Above I gave just an example. You need to change arguments based on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!:) Can you perhaps explain me what is webClientBuilder, and how to include that in code as well? As I've discovered, first way is not working for some reason for me..Thank you very much for your time..

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @slomil, But ```RestTemplate``` is somehow easier to use. Because there are so many resources and examples on the internet. Probably you are making a mistake in using ```RestTemplate```. Main difference between two, ```WebClient``` is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question,should I import WebClient from somewhere, or should I create class WebClient? It seems I can't import it.. I've looked here also as well https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient and there are dependencies to add, but still cannot import it..(if that should be done at all) ..sorry, import is working now..

Comment: You also need to declare ```webflux``` library in you ```pom.xml```. ```WebFlux``` is used mainly in ```reactive``` Spring. Updated my answer.

Comment: sorry for asking this.. I've posted in my question link to my question inspired by that original question.. where I think I did all correctly, but just couldn't avoid error while reading content of response using EntityUtils.toString(entity) function..sorry for asking this, but is it perhaps possible for you to take one quick look at that? I really don't know what can be problem with it.. searched google over and over again..Thank you very much in each case, you helped a lot:)